# True for all values but 1, cannot figure out why (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

My loop goes over a range of cells and compares the values:

```
For k = 7 To wsPlany.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If wsPlany.Cells(k, 1) = datu Then
        'code here
    End If
Next k
```

Basically the cells are cells with numbers, `1, 2, 3 ...` and the `datu`is a number too. It all works but for the value 1 and I cannot figure out why.

Even debug.printing something like: wsPlany.Cells(k, 1), datu and comparing them into next line confirms that if value is 2 or higher, it will return true for that line, if it is 1 exactly, it returns false as if it were comparing with other number (but I see they are the same as they are side by side in debug.print).

Comment: a) try `If Round(wsPlany.Cells(k, 1).value2, 0) = Round(datu, 0)` to remove floating point errors from consideration and b) try `If CLng(wsPlany.Cells(k, 1).value2) = CLng(datu)` to remove text that look like numbers from consideration (e.g. *"1"* ≠ *1*).

Comment: But I mean if it works for 2...n, it should logically work for 1 too as they are all just simply written values in a cells (the 1 is no different from 2 apart from being 1 and not 2). I will, however, try this.

Comment: What datatypes are used for `k` and `datu`?

Comment: I have actually figured out the problem... I was wrong - the "1" is stored as string, the other ones as integer and have solved it now =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple addition of 1 line where I turn the values to `Integers` no matter what data type they were before solved the problem.

```
For k = 7 To wsPlany.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'turns the values to integers first
    wsPlany.Cells(k, 1).Value = CInt(wsPlany.Cells(k,1))

    If wsPlany.Cells(k, 1) = datu Then
        'code here
    End If
Next k
```